# Divide multi-byte number

Tags: math, division, low-level, integer-division

If I only have a routine to divide two (unsigned) bytes, how can I divide a two-byte number by a one-byte number (both unsigned)?

The divisor is always 10 (which I know may mean there is a clever multiply-and-shift approach to this), but I'm also interested in a general method.

Comment: What architecture? Note that x86 specifically does this simply by `DIV r/m8`.

Comment: The general method is to implement long division (either restoring or non-restoring).  See Knuth *The Art of Computer Programming, vol. 1 Fundamental Algorithms* for a good treatment.

Comment: I'd like to help you but you do have to specify the machine architecture.

Comment: It's not a specific architecture that exists, it's a hobby project :p

Comment: @andrepd Please use `@username` to get a fast reply. Even if it is a hobby project, you have to specify your target architecture because the optimal code for each architecture can be vastly different. Assembly is not like some high-level language.

Comment: @xiver77 But this is not strictly about any assembly language (as a matter of fact might be better to remove that tag), but about mathematics / abstract low-level programming.

Comment: Basically, there are 2 ways. First, you can do long division in base `2^8`. The long division you learned in school is done in base `10`. You can do the same in base `2^8`. Second, as you already know, you can do a multiply and shift. To divide by `10` the expression you need is `(uint16_t)x * 205 >> 11`, in C terms. Either way, the low level code will differ *a lot* depending on whether the hardware natively supports operations dealing with 16-bit integers, or whether the hardware has a carry flag and operations handling the carry bits.

Comment: Or even whether the hardware can bitshift arbitrarily many times at once (some chips can't).

Comment: @xiver77 Right, I thought of that, but in long division won't we still need to divide a two-byte number? Say 63/4: divide 6/4 get 1 (the first digit of the quotient) and remainder 2, add 2×10 to the next digit and get 23, then divide 23/4 get 5 (the second digit of the quotient) and remainder 3. So we still need to divide 23/4 (a two-digit number)

Comment: @andrepd That's correct. The point is, when you divide 63 by 4, the quotient does not fit in the base (which is 10 in this case). But when you divide 23 by 4, you know the quotient fits in the base. Most CPU that can do hardware division supports the dividend's size being twice the size of the machine word (like 128-bit for a 64-bit machine), given that the quotient fits in the size of the machine word. So if you have an 8-bit machine, you'll be able to do 12345/123 with a single hardware division, but not with 12345/12.

Comment: If your machine doesn't have hardware division, you'll have to implement it yourself, but in this case, you'll be much better off using multiply-and-shift if you know the divisor.

Comment: @fuz: *Vol II, Seminumerical Algorithms*.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Right!  How could I forget?  It's chapter 4, *Arithmetic* of course.